# How does this code work for JUnit in JAVA?

Tags: java

I have the following code for JUnit testing:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
public class JUnitHelloWorld {
    protected String s;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        s = "HELLO WORLD";
    }
    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldSuccess() {
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        assertEquals("hello world", s);
    }
    // will fail even if testHelloWorldSuccess is called first
    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldFail() {
        assertEquals("hello world", s);
    }
}
```

Now, according to the comment, why will the second method fail even if the first method is called first? isn't the first method changing the value of s to lowercase?

Answer (score 4):

`@Before` happens before each test. This means the order you run them in does not matter as it will always perform the setup then do the test.

The tag `@BeforeClass` will give you the behaviour you are expecting. This runs once before any of your tests start.

Comment: Indeed switching to @BeforeClass will get provide the behavior, but then that will be bad testing practice :-P

Comment: In this case it is bad testing practice because the order of execution matters. I included the `@BeforeClass` so the OP would understand how to get the behaviour they were expecting from `@Before`.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit does not run each test case (method with @Test) in order of your code. That is why each test case must be independent of each other.

Also setup method with @Before tag will always get run before each of your test method.

So likelihood (but not necessarily) the order of execution of your code are:

1. setup()
2. testHelloWorldSuccess()
3. setup()
4. testHelloWorldFail()

But it might also run:

1. setup()
2. testHelloWorldFail()
3. setup()
4. testHelloWorldSuccess()

Answer (score 0):

for JUnit , the order of testcase execution is not fixed. It may happen that you wrote a method m2  after method m1 and while execution, m2 gets executed first. The best approach is your test case should not be based on the testcase execution order.
try @BeforeClass if you want something to be executed once for the whole class only.

For the above scenario try this:

```
    protected String s;
    private int flag ;
       @BeforeClass
       public beforeClass(){
           flag = 0;
       }
        @Before
        public void setup() {
            s = "HELLO WORLD";

        }
        @Test
        public void testHelloWorldSuccess() {
        flag = 1;
            s = s.toLowerCase();
            assertEquals("hello world", s);
        }
        // won't fail even if testHelloWorldSuccess is called first
        @Test
        public void testHelloWorldFail() {
        if(flag == 1)
            assertEquals("hello world", s);
        else
        assertEquals("HELLO WORLD", s);
        }
```